# Validate control just if another control validated

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have 2 textboxes, and I want to validate the second just if the first one is correct.
I don't find way to do it.

Any solution?

Thank you.

Comment: `if-else`? I can't say more because we don't have any information about your validation..

Comment: Yes, but where? Is there any validating event?

Comment: How do you validate your first textbo? Are you using validators? Are you manually checking the content?

Comment: How about using a `ValidatedFlag`? On first text box's text is changed, `ValidatedFlag = false;` when it is validated: `ValidatedFlag= true;` then, when you want to validate the second one, check that flag. If it is false, so the first one is not validated yet.

Comment: I'm using validators

Comment: But where can I check the flag? I need a Validating event..